# Can I debug a pointer as array?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

For example,
I wanna watch pA

```
int *pA = new int[LEN];
```

Then in visual studio, I can see only pA[0] in watch-window

I try to view '(int (*)[LEN])pA', but it does not work

I don't want to make

```
int (*test)[LEN] = (int (*)[LEN])pA
```

to debug

How can I see dynamic allocated pointer as a static array in debugger of VS2010?

Comment: You should probably be using `std::vector<int>`, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write `pA,10` (or how many elements you want to see) in the watch window.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Quick Watch:

- First know the value of `LEN`.  Say, it is 100.
- Then, type `pA,100` to see all the 100 elements.